# Azure pipeline 'WinRMCustomScriptExtension' underlying connection was closed in non-public VM

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, winrm

In Azure pipeline when creating a VM through deployment template, we have the option to 'Configure with WinRM agent' as given below. [image: Configure with WinRM agent]

This acts as a custom extension behind the scenes. But the downloading of this custom extension can be blocked by an internal vnet in Azure. This is the error we are getting.

```
<datetime> Adding extension 'WinRMCustomScriptExtension' on virtual machine <vmname>
<datetime> Failed to add the extension to the vm: <vmname>. Error: "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'WinRMCustomScriptExtension'. Error message: \"Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "
```

Since the files cannot be downloaded, I am thinking of a couple of solutions:

1. How can I know which powershell files azure is using to setup winrm?
2. Location to store files would be storage account (same vnet as VM)
3. Perhaps not use WinRM at all and use custom script extension to resolve
   everything (with all files from storage account). I hope error from extension stops the pipeline if it happens.
4. Is there a better solution to resolve this? To me it looks like a bad design by azure as it is not covering non-public VMs.

EDIT:
Found answer to #1) https://aka.ms/vstsconfigurewinrm. This was shown in Raw logs of the pipeline when diagnostics were enabled

Answer (score 0):

1. Even if you know - how does it help you? It won't be able to download them anyway and you cant really tell it to use local files
2. If you enable service endpoins and allow your subnet to talk to the storage account - it should work
3. there is a way to configure WinRM when you create the VM. [Keyvault example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-winrm-keyvault-windows/)
4. You could use script extension like you wanted to as well, but script extension has to download stuff to the Vm as well. [Example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-winrm-windows)